# Send pdf in Email Without Saving it on Server Using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, pdf

I have been trying to send email with attachment of `pdf` produced by `MPDF` library in codeigniter from my view, I have successfully converted my file to `PDF` or i think i did, but i cannot find any way to attach that file to email using given functionality in CodeIgniter.

In Documentation of CodeIgnitor a confusing and incomplete description of `attach` function is suggesting this:

> $this->email->attach($buffer, 'attachment', 'report.pdf',
>   'application/pdf');

Where `$buffer` is string `report.pdf` will be the fileName where of attachment with email,

Now my concern here is can i attach my generated view something like this:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '20M');
// load library
$this->load->library('pdf');
$pdf = $this->pdf->load();

// boost the memory limit if it's low ;)
$html = $this->load->view('reports/someReport', array('var' => 123), true);
// render the view into HTML
$pdf->WriteHTML($html);
$this->email->attach($pdf->Output('', 'S'), 'attachment', 'report.pdf', 'application/pdf'); // is this okay or something is wrong here ?
```

How can i attach it successfully with email and send it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can save PDF file in your project folder like `attach`. And then this pdf location set email attachment. Like bellow :  :

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '20M');
// load library
$this->load->library('pdf');
$pdf = $this->pdf->load();

// boost the memory limit if it's low ;)
$html = $this->load->view('reports/someReport', array('var' => 123), true);
// render the view into HTML

$pdfFilePath = FCPATH . "attach/pdf_name.pdf";
$pdf->WriteHTML($html);
$pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "F");

$result = $this->email
            ->from('example@test.com', 'From name')
            ->to('test@test.com')
            ->subject($subject)
            ->message($body)
            ->attach($pdfFilePath)
            ->send();
$this->email->clear($pdfFilePath);
if($result) {
    echo "Send";
    unlink($pdfFilePath); //for delete generated pdf file. 
}
?>
```

Comment: Problem with above code is it is saving the file each time email is sent, is there anyway to bypass that ?

Comment: Just inform me. now send attach with pdf?

Comment: let me test it.

Comment: i received this error `<B>mPDF error: </B>Unable to create output file: /home/myusername/public_html/app_rest/attach/pdf_name.pdf ` , here `app_rest` folder is root directory of codeignitor

Comment: create successfully pdf file in `app_rest/attach` folder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128898/discussion-between-razib-al-mamun-and-mr-z).

Comment: if gave path as only filename `pdf_name.pdf` it worked , i received email with attachment and file , but i am not sure that what happened to file which was generated on server

Comment: if send is success you can delete this pdf file `if($result) {
 echo "Send";
 unlink($pdfFilePath);
}`

Comment: can you please update your answer code , so it will help someone who read this question